# what C/C++ image processing libraries are used on-board satellites/rovers?

Tags: rovers, remote-sensing, image-processing

- Given that a full blown linux is rarely used in spacecrafts, can popular image processing libraries like opencv be use in space applications?
- Since radiation hardened processors are much less capable than recent processors, can real time image processing performance achieved using processors with 'space heritage'.
- Do space software developers go for custom C++ libraries for image processing? or is there a commonly used open source c++ library?

Comment: i dont think any spacecraft have live image processing, because what would they do with it? they are all remote or pre planned controlled

Comment: Computer vision would be pretty useful for docking and landers.

Comment: How do people implement such real-time computer vision algorithms?

Comment: @ikraseand identifying humanoid aliens

Comment: I found NASA's computer vision library  at https://github.com/visionworkbench/visionworkbench . But I am not sure which of their projects used them. There was some information about the library [here](https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/asr/groups/intelligent-robotics/nasa-vision-workbench/#Approach)